# Gcloud app deploy fails using python+django+gunicorn + worker failed to boot

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gunicorn, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a website/webapp using django... constructed app.yaml and requirements.txt... everything done and when I hit `gcloud app deploy` , I have this following error log at the end..

```
DONE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                    
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-03-18 03:14:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python

api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

# the PROJECT-DIRECTORY is the one with settings.py and wsgi.py
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT ~/NovUs/rec/rec.wsgi
# specific to a GUnicorn HTTP server deployment
env: flex 
# for Google Cloud Flexible App Engine

# any environment variables you want to pass to your application.
# accessible through os.environ['VARIABLE_NAME']
env_variables:
# the secret key used for the Django app (from PROJECT-DIRECTORY/settings.py)
  SECRET_KEY: '***i removed this***' 
  DEBUG: 'False' # always False for deployment

# everything after /cloudsql/ can be found by entering >> gcloud sql instances describe DATABASE-NAME << in your Terminal
# the DATABASE-NAME is the name you gave your project's PostgreSQL database
# the second line from the describe output called connectionName can be copied and pasted after /cloudsql/
  DB_HOST: '/cloudsql/ final-234816:us-central1:novusdb'
  DB_PORT: '5432' # PostgreSQL port
  DB_NAME: 'novusdb'
  DB_USER: 'postgres' # either 'postgres' (default) or one you created on the PostgreSQL instance page
  DB_PASSWORD: ''

  STATIC_URL: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET-NAME/static/' # this is the url that you sync static files to

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /
  script: home.app

- url: /index\.html
  script: home.app

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: not_found.app

beta_settings:
# from command >> gcloud sql instances describe DATABASE-NAME <<
  cloud_sql_instances: final-234816:us-central1:novusdb 

#runtime_config:
#python_version: 2 # enter your Python version BASE ONLY here. Enter 2 for 2.7.9 or 3 for 3.6.4

#manual_scaling:
#  instances: 1
#resources:
#  cpu: 1
#  memory_gb: 0.5
#  disk_size_gb: 10
```

here in my settings.py
`WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rec.wsgi.application'`
even if i change it to `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'`
 it doesnt solve, the error remains same.

and i have tried editing the entrypoint with `main:app` the problem is same....
someone please solve this. thankyou

Comment: Try using, in your `app.yaml`'s entrypoint line, a relative, not a full path to your WSGI application (relative to the app.yaml's location). Nothing above the directory in which `app.yaml` is located exists on GAE.

Comment: Any luck with this? Think I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there could be 2 problems, ran into this a while ago when deploying a Dash application on Google App Engine.

There could be a version conflict in GAE's gunicorn version. Use gunicorn 19.7.1 or higher instead. I had the same problem when using an older version of gunicorn.

The other conflict could be that requirements.txt is not in the same directory as your main.py entrypoint. Therefore the app will be deployed without all the packages installed, which will return no error when deploying to GAE.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.yaml add the default gunicorn entrypoint line, but also add a longer timeout to suit your needs: `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT YOURSITE.wsgi --timeout 120`